# Batch file - copy file from parent folder - why the cmd file closed adter the run?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm using this code to copy files from the parent folder. But as soon as the code finish the execution, teh CMD window is closed. So I cannot read the result to see what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
COPY ..\File.*
@echo The script is complete.
```

This need to copy the file "File.exe" from the parent folder to the current. then print a success message, and stay open, so I'll can see if there is any error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `pause` at the end, that way you have to press a key before the batch file closes.